# Communication between uipath and the taxonomy manager ended unexpectedly

Tags: uipath

[image]
Large version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUVsN.png

[image]

[image]

I have this error when opening taxonomy manager (Communication between UiPath and the taxonomy manager ended unexpectedly) after I tried to upgrade these two packages CefSharp and intelligent OCR in order to solve that error, but I still have the error. How can I solve this error?